# virtualbox ubuntu server can not ping 192.168.1.1 using bridged networking

Tags: ubuntu

I have ubuntu server installed on virtualbox recently.

It work **just** fine when I use the NAT(transisint).

But my host computer require access to the VM ubuntu server using **http protocal** which is not suppoted using port forword.

```
When it's set to use bridged network, it failed to ping 192.168.1.1.
```

After 1 or more hour googling, I guess it's something wrong about the firewall,
    but all the solutions I found can only work on **Ubuntu Desktop**.

So how should I adjust my VM to make it accessable using http protocal from the host?

Thanks in advanced.